# What could the issue be that's causing not readable (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

What could the issue be that's causing not readable (python).

Using macos
latest python

Issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/husaynjaffer/Desktop/SNEAKER_BOT_NAKEDUK_0.0.00/snkrsrequests.py", line 65, in <module>
    printy5=(f.read())
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.nike.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 's_ecid=MCMID%7C64464983321989159218366443183082782711; AMCV_F0935E09512D2C270A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=1994364360%7CMCMID%7C64464983321989159218366443183082782711%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1624323611s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C3.4.0; AnalysisUserId=754766ad-c5a1-42a6-99b8-4b63b84f5879; anonymousId=BF3145B3DD565EBA7087ACD3AD3854DA; _gcl_au=1.1.1389968986.1624316416; _ga=GA1.2.655248135.1624316416; _scid=9292ee2f-b821-4f33-a8e5-d1ea173a4881; _fbp=fb.1.1624316416726.1204607247; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU5tRTVNRFJrWXpjdFpqWTFNaTAwTkRZMUxUaGxZek10T0RRMU9EUmpNR1prWldRMg; rmStore=atm:pixel; bc_nike_india_triggermail=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217a30cd8e7cb8f-0eac607c6b1057-34647600-13c680-17a30cd8e7d181c%22%2C%22bc_persist_updated%22%3A%201624329927224%2C%22g_search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%7D; cid=undefined%7Cundefined; bc_nike_australia_triggermail=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217a30cd8e7cb8f-0eac607c6b1057-34647600-13c680-17a30cd8e7d181c%22%2C%22bc_persist_updated%22%3A%201624368895316%2C%22g_search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%7D; ajs_anonymous_id=%222facb0bf-8c3f-4012-a522-5d05c9d7131b%22; _sp_id.759a=606dce70-c967-465b-a2ad-2d29aa13a9f9.1624381351.1.1624381351.1624381351.3cbcb5fd-46bc-46d3-88ec-797abe20c443; lls=3; RES_TRACKINGID=70867820678928342; ResonanceSegment=1; guidS=4bbd5ab6-8c3e-45dd-d78e-e7deae831c8e; guidU=50a342d4-6465-44fb-c3b3-cad6d2d9b273; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1624662452914r0.43432587032371495; bc_nike_triggermail=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217a30cd8e7cb8f-0eac607c6b1057-34647600-13c680-17a30cd8e7d181c%22%2C%22bc_persist_updated%22%3A%201624662919493%2C%22g_search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%22bc_id%22%3A%20-294634438%2C%22bluecoreSiteIsMember%22%3A%20true%2C%22cart_total%22%3A%200%7D; _gid=GA1.2.1057075377.1624763802; bc_nike_singapore_triggermail=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217a30cd8e7cb8f-0eac607c6b1057-34647600-13c680-17a30cd8e7d181c%22%2C%22bc_persist_updated%22%3A%201625280508415%2C%22g_search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%22bc_id%22%3A%20-294634438%2C%22bluecoreSiteIsMember%22%3A%20true%2C%22cart_total%22%3A%20480%7D; bc_nike_malaysia_triggermail=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217a30cd8e7cb8f-0eac607c6b1057-34647600-13c680-17a30cd8e7d181c%22%2C%22bc_persist_updated%22%3A%201625280522414%2C%22g_search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%22bc_id%22%3A%20-294634438%2C%22bluecoreSiteIsMember%22%3A%20true%2C%22cart_total%22%3A%20480%7D; snkrsCoachmarksSeen=true; slCheck=jVs44jvOijn7cQEmJhBytYlpOSaB3qm3iKjA5KOgvosWTK5+ogUzdwgrttgHK0VGCHX9BWUVBGmU6EnBsSflXcbgzfZWoCQ3JZGYhGz44u2CLaVOrz8T+iaP7yLpU8rC; llCheck=Dz/guics3S/1WtmpB8wlOYUPQKZ9fwpoFdGA2HuGPtSUY5wYcIFDbgMCE5VSR/5pwnZX3qQ1lOtmI/5LYeGdO3FOhxojSj0fjPDMTbzkDmGUPbd4cjid1uvA2mIeXdljbEJ9hzSY9VcNOTACB30DpeExQZXFomMmOoaT3XaJBOQ=; sls=3; bc_nike_great_britain_triggermail=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217a30cd8e7cb8f-0eac607c6b1057-34647600-13c680-17a30cd8e7d181c%22%2C%22bc_persist_updated%22%3A%201625585405187%2C%22g_search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%22bc_id%22%3A%20-294634438%2C%22bluecoreSiteIsMember%22%3A%20true%2C%22cart_total%22%3A%200%7D; AMCV_B73502BE533095810A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1075005958%7CMCMID%7C64464983321989159218366443183082782711%7CMCIDTS%7C18815%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1625613435s%7CNONE%7CMCAAMLH-1626211035%7C7%7CMCAAMB-1626211035%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI%7CvVersion%7C4.4.1; CONSUMERCHOICE=ca/en_gb; NIKE_COMMERCE_COUNTRY=CA; NIKE_COMMERCE_LANG_LOCALE=en_GB; forterToken=f4dc978130a744f3b38a448ae065b963_1625686602745__UDF43_11ck; bc_nike_canada_triggermail=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217a30cd8e7cb8f-0eac607c6b1057-34647600-13c680-17a30cd8e7d181c%22%2C%22bc_persist_updated%22%3A%201625585481769%2C%22g_search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%22bc_id%22%3A%20-294634438%2C%22bluecoreSiteIsMember%22%3A%20true%2C%22cart_total%22%3A%200%7D; _aw_m_16331=16331_1624545250_37ee048b2e8b17f351e21d8d520f4947; _uetsid=19071930d6f611eb803f5b2a1e95689c; _uetvid=7180e180d2e411eb9c63856fd664c5c0; _abck=F10BECE8D36CB73DA17C1FB4ECA24433~-1~YAAQFMaISLa2EFR6AQAALP54ggab2ppbGyRiheHuWzbFSfbLqz2qXyvN3edYc33SAPXm3MuetdfOqKPuCt3wOh+WSgHemCjO600/ZqXDeZKMCseAZVjOoWUOza/6G9moW+stevzy3iRKuMISnBc1FQs0g3fRxyCQ3634UQb8ZeWK4LAIqE1v1y9vE6cdOkbl68q/spr3RRokYDwcUwajQ6XIC0mbQTeURK91dmHsHGHHtQe6ZiDiqHkyXRscFKFOKpQyJyS6AS3b+Sr4FvflBUfpC7cEHtR3ckBg+xHFh21KVj/VGPWDC90K+HpkDs1XCBuUil5lmfBVKI3RSaXc//rYgxbW7vDOtm+UrqcGCvm3zdk1fpdJB1jvUGVlYYWM5kKQd1XpiS/otUL794DjIok6RSZiay5nTxqVImpcjxEh3Or6IuO58LhxKu5e38MszlkNb943THawnkOAvp7yt0//ccjfrg==~-1~-1~-1; RT="z=1&dm=nike.com&si=8a7ea01d-d4f7-4740-88f2-c362f0b33c28&ss=kqtvtnti&sl=2&tt=6dg&bcn=%2F%2F17d09915.akstat.io%2F&ld=93n&ul=1mgz&hd=1mhc"; ak_bmsc=C92DF0CCE146E098E7117F91FCCC2CF7~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQjsaISCbyixp6AQAA0uW6gwyk6OyQVaX4Eqh0D4FO4ZI3IluP+JzZvtw6NyVvUFWtnp6sUNST8jeqGOLSZ5AHdDFoR5XZ8TNAlX1iCwLJpCoog2o9RfgDN6/H4Mdes801717hehtGPQfBizNsN9QihGF/+zpmJ1WTZWmeKtn3FeVW0kTfev5ttuycqQEN2m2fiBr6NEewFmgXZHQ7LXsgYfj+KZ2f8/JFFNbaGVVD8QzZaFMUDI/rQKfZvmr3jDOpRkUxGIjxDGBBG5Kv6seOMYmZQk3QsQNcUM9zYq5vc/6O0urD6rZN2hBkrxca5sw/muaotr5hHXMy0vXxEdetqIk11qnsBAnqWa1XsV6k96UWs/q397Rk/RRJGXQ0k1FDXhF8IFQ=',
    'dnt': '1',
}

params = (
    ('filter', ['marketplace(CA)', 'language(en-GB)', 'channelId(010794e5-35fe-4e32-aaff-cd2c74f89d61)', 'exclusiveAccess(true,false)']),
)

response = requests.get('https://api.nike.com/product_feed/threads/v2/', headers=headers, params=params)

response = requests.get('https://api.nike.com/product_feed/threads/v2/?filter=marketplace%28CA%29&filter=language%28en-GB%29&filter=channelId%28010794e5-35fe-4e32-aaff-cd2c74f89d61%29&filter=exclusiveAccess%28true,false%29', headers=headers)
a = 1

f = open("demofile3.txt", "a")
f.write(response.text)
f.close()
print ("writing response")
while a == 1:
    #open and read the file after the appending:d
    f = open("demofile3.txt", "r")
    printy=(f.read())
    print ("reading response")

    printy1= (printy.partition(",\"styleColor\":\"")[2])
    print ("making split")

    f = open("demofile3txt", "a")
    f.write(printy1)
    f.close()
    print ("writing split")

    f = open("demofile3.txt", "r")
    printy2=(f.read())
    print ("reading split")


    def first2(s):
        return s[:2]

    print ("doing thinbg")
    printy3=(printy2[:10])

    f = open("demoofile1.txt", "a")
    printy5=(f.read())
    f.close()
    print ("writing split")

    printy4= (printy5.partition(printy3)[2])

    print (printy4)

    if printy3!=printy4:
        f = open("demoofile1.txt", "a")
        f.write(printy3+",")
        f.close()
        print ("done ")
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: unrelated_ You should switch to use contexthandling `with open(...) as f:` and scope the accesses - maybe that gives you clarity. Check how you open stuff and what you do after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the file with the mode parameter for open() set to "a" which is for writing only.

Here is a summary of the different parameters:
from: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

```
"r"   Opens a file for reading only.
"r+"  Opens a file for both reading and writing.
"rb"  Opens a file for reading only in binary format.
"rb+" Opens a file for both reading and writing in binary format.
"w"   Opens a file for writing only.
"a"   Open for writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.
"a+"  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.
```

So for use case to read and write to the file try changing it to:

```py
f = open("demoofile1.txt", "r+")
```